# How to find different between two dates in aura Component?

Tags: javascript, aura, date

I am try to get number of days between two dates.
here is my code--

```
Var first = new Date('2021-09-01T03:24:00');
Var second = new Date('2022-09-02T05:24:00');
Var Difference = second.getdate() - first.getdate();
console.log('Difference day---->' + Difference);
```

Output:

Difference day---->1 day

But Correct Output:

Difference---->366 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) only returns the "day" part of the date.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
  
                                    //Milliseconds * Seconds in a Hour * Hours in a Day
var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
```